# React JS componentWillUnmount Only Sometimes Called

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to invoke componentWillUnmount every time I make a new request?
Right now, it is called only sometimes. It's not even called when I refresh the browser.

Situation:

I have a like/dislike module just like stack overflow's. Initially, I sent an ajax request every time a user clicks like or dislike. Because this was so slow and also because I had to disable the buttons to prevent duplications, I instead decided to do an optimistic update. Basically, I just update states when user clicks like or dislike, and I send the ajax request during the componentWillUnmount method. If it doesn't get called, all the likes and dislikes disappear :(

Comment: doc says "Invoked immediately before a component is unmounted from the DOM" (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount). Isn't it what you want?

Comment: The name (componentWillUnmount) suggests what you said. My question is, why isn't it called every time I make a new request?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding exactly when a component is unmounted?

Comment: Your request on the same page triggers re-rendering all components but not necessarily unmounting them from the page. You'd probably see that being triggered if you move to a different page.

Comment: It only gets triggered immediately when I move to certain pages. In some cases, componentWillUnmount gets called when I move to a different page, and then come back to the initial page.

Comment: Could you give more details of what you exactly want to achieve? Maybe `componentWillUnmount` is not the correct tool here.

Comment: I have a like/dislike module just like stack overflow's. Initially, I sent an ajax request every time a user clicks like or dislike. Because this was so slow and also because I had to disable the buttons to prevent duplications, I instead decided to do an optimistic update. Basically, I just update states when user clicks like or dislike, and I send the ajax request during the componentWillUnmount method. If it doesn't get called, all the likes and dislikes disappear :(

Comment: Making ajax requests has nothing to do with componentWillUnmount, unless for some reason the result of that request is removing DOM elements? You would send the request from a click event, not in componentWillUnmount - which is used for any additional cleanup you need to do (you probably don't need to use it)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want componentWillUnmount for this. If you're using Flux with React, it's pretty simple: when the store notifies the component that it has changed (after an Ajax request was made), you can ask the store if the update went through successfully. If it hasn't, you can roll back your optimistic update. Are you using Flux?

Comment: I'm using Ruby on Rails with the react-rails gem, and I haven't tried using flux. Can you think of a solution without using flux, or would you say flux is a necessity?

Comment: Not a necessity, no. I would recommend it, though. It makes life a lot easier -- although there's an initial period of "how the heck is this thing supposed to work?!?"

Comment: If I were to go without using flux, what is the suggested approach?

Comment: Yeah, people are getting too hung up on the AJAX here.  OP is trying to find a consistently executed method that he knows will occur after user has made a choice and at that time -- within said method -- do something (in this case it just so happens to be an AJAX request).

Answer (score 0):

Just before updating the state, you can check the current state. If user already clicked like or dislike, do not send the ajax request. Otherwise, send the ajax request.

I observed componentWillMount and componentDidMount being called every time, but componentWillUnmount not being called on unmount immediately. Thus two or more react class instances of the same type were binded to the same dom object and I faced issues. componentWillUnmount gets called way later as a batch cleaning all binded objects. I am using react 0.14.2.